# Trigger mousedown and include e.which in the event

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts, eventtrigger

Im using highcharts and jquery. Instead of the normal legend-system to show the name of my series, i have my own `ul` filled with `li` containing the data-serie names and information.

I'm simulating desktop folder behaviour in this list with jquery ui `.draggable()` and a few custom events that listen for user holding `ctrl` or `shift`. (used for selecting and deselecting multiple list elements at once)

What I'm also doing is letting the user click on the line in the highcharts graph to select the `li` element in the series list.

Problem: I want to for example hold control and click on two or more data-series in the graph to highlight those series in the list.

I am able to trigger the `li click event` by clicking on the series in the graph, but holding `ctrl` or `shift` does nothing. So how do I send "e.which" to an event I'm triggering elsewhere?

I have a lot of code, so i'll just post the most relevant stuff. Ask away for clearification.

This is the click event in highcharts that triggers the `li click event`. I haven't forgotten the `mouseup` event, i just havent gotten to it yet

```
click: function (event) {
$(newDisplay).find('.destination li[data-description="' + this.name + '"]').trigger('mousedown', [event])
},'
```

This is the whole li `mousedown` and `mouseup` event

```
    var targetArea, lastClicked,
        slct = 'ui-selected',
        slctC = '.ui-selected';

    if (!parameterTarget)
    { targetArea = '.lnSeries'; }
    else
    { targetArea = parameterTarget; }

    $(targetArea)
        .off()
        .on('mousedown', 'li', function (e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
                if ($(this).hasClass(slct)) {
                    $(this).removeClass(slct);
                    lastClicked = null;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).addClass(slct);
                    lastClicked = $(this)
                }

            } else if (e.shiftKey) {
                if ($(slctC).length == 0) {
                    lastClicked = $(this);
                }

                if ($(this).index() > $(lastClicked).index()
                    && $(this).siblings().is(lastClicked)) {

                    $(lastClicked).nextUntil($(e.target).next()).addBack().addClass(slct);
                } else if ($(this).index() < $(lastClicked).index()
                    && $(this).siblings().is(lastClicked)) {

                    $(lastClicked).prevUntil($(e.target).prev()).addBack().addClass(slct);

                } else {
                    lastClicked = $(this)
                    $(this).addClass(slct);
                }

            } else {
                lastClicked = $(e.target);
                if (!($(this).hasClass(slct))) {
                    $(slctC).removeClass(slct);
                    $(this).addClass(slct);
                }
            }

            infoTable();

        })
        .on('mouseup', 'li', function (e) {
            if (($(slctC).length > 1) && !(e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey || e.metaKey)) {
                $(slctC).removeClass(slct);
                $(this).addClass(slct);
            } else if ($(slctC).length == 1) {

            }

        })
```

I'm sure this is a problem with my `e` but I just don't understand how to approach this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.hasClass('slct')` instead oft `.hasClass(slct)` ? `slct` doesn't appear to be a variable, it should be a string. This can lead to `slct is undefined` and break the script.

Comment: It's a variable, i'll edit my post to include that. All the clicking in the list works as intended. I just cant replicate it by clicking on the graph lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the data passed by trigger method inside targeted handler. This is the way you could do it, but not sure it will work in your case:

```
$(targetArea)
    .off()
    .on('mousedown', 'li', function (e, data) {
       e = data || e;
        // all rest of logic there...
    });
```